# No Credentials to try in Hudson

Tags: svn, hudson

I have a Problem with Hudson. I want to make a Job Configuration. I have my C++ project on an SVN-Server. But whene i give my repository URL for the Suversion it dosent function. The failure is:

*SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: NO credential to try. Authentication failed.*

I have made an authetication but it doesen work.

Thank you for your Help.

Best reguards

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your Hudson server at the following URL:

```
http://<hudsonrul>/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential
```

This will allow you to specify a top-level SVN URL and appropriate credentials. In most cases, `username/password authentication` is enough.

***Edit:***
You should try accessing the SVN server from command line, to verify if this is an SVN server issue, or a Hudson issues.

On command line, type:
`svn --no-auth-cache --username [yourusername] --password [yourpassword] info http://svn.server.url`

Replace `[yourusername]` and `[yourpassword]` with your username and password, without the square brackets. Replace `http://svn.server.url` with address of your SVN server

You should get back basic SVN repo info, such as last changed dates, UUID, revision, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. I have do this but it doesent work -.-. Can that be a problem with my Serversecuryti or an other Problem?

Comment: Sorry, there is not much more that I can say. Maybe your SVN server has some unorthodox configuration, maybe you have an unstable build of Hudson that has issues in SVN plugin. You can try upgrading Hudson. You should also try accessing the SVN server from command line, to verify that is is not a Hudson issue. I will update the answer with instructions on accessing the server from command line

Answer (score 0):

You should check your repository address and svn external link address.
Hudson credential only works when exact match your repo address and registered address, In my case I did registered both IP address and url

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).